# Multiple google fonts in wordpress not working properly

Tags: html, css, wordpress, fonts, google-font-api

I am developing a wordpress website and want to integrate multiple fonts with different weights. I have added the following code for that:

> wp_enqueue_style( 'fonts',
>   '//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:300,400,700,900|Poppins:300,400,700|Work+Sans:300,400,700,900',
>   array(), null);

Now suppose i want to use Poppins font with font-weight 400 then it is not loading in the website. Instead the font-weight appears to look like 900.

Clearly, i understood that as i am using so many fonts some of the font-weights are not actually getting loaded.

What is the proper way to do this? How to solve this issue? How do i manage to load all of them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

could you try adding `http:` on your font link and `false` instead of `array(),null`?

```
wp_enqueue_style( 'fonts', 'http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:300,400,700,900|Poppins:300,400,700|Work+Sans:300,400,700,900', false);
```

Comment: Yes, it worked. Thank you so much. I replaced array() with false and now all the fonts-weights are loading. However, i read that when u are on http:// and https:// both network then its safe to remove the protocol declaration. and simple start with '//fonts.googleapis.com/'. I am so relieved. :D